# Database table is not creating in JavaFx

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1, ddl

```
private DatabaseHandler() {
    createConnection();
    COUNTRYNAME();
    STATETBL();
}

void createConnection() {
    try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"postgres", "root");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Country Table

```
void COUNTRYNAME() {
    String TABLE_NAME = "COUNTRY_TBL";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
        if (tables.next()) {
          System.out.println("Table " + TABLE_NAME + "already exists. Ready for go!");
        } else {
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                    + " COUNTRYname varchar(20),\n"
                    + " COUNTRY2CHAR varchar(50),\n"
                    + " DESCR varchar(50),\n"
                    + " DESCRSHORT varchar(50)"+")");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " --- setupDatabase");
    } finally {
    }
}
```

State Table

```
void STATETBL() {
    String TABLE_NAME = "STATE_TBL";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
        if (tables.next()) {
            System.out.println("Table " + TABLE_NAME + "already exists. Ready for go!");
        } else {
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + " id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                    + " COUNTRYid varchar(20),\n"
                    + " STATE varchar(50),\n"
                    + " DESCR varchar(50),\n"
                    + " DESCRSHORT varchar(50),\n"
                    + " NUMERIC_CD varchar(50),\n"
                    + " FOREIGN KEY (COUNTRYid) REFERENCES COUNTRY_TBL(id)"+")");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " --- setupDatabase");
    } finally {
    }
}
```

When i execute the above code the CountryName table gets generated in my database but my State table is not generating

Comment: Do you get any errors? If yes which one? Unrelated, but: you should close the `ResultSet` that you get from the `getTables()` call

Comment: syntax error at or "(" at + " DESCR varchar(50),\n"

Comment: `STATE` is a reserved word IIRC, not sure if it is the cause though.